# Using boto3 to download files from EFS Amazon

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am following this documentation to download files from EFS
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/efs.html

I have read through the whole documentation and could not figure out a way to download files. Only possible way is that using: generate_presigned_url().
However, the documentation for this part is very limited. I have tried so many times but got stuck. Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EFS creates a **filesystem** for you. For example, if you are using linux, it will be available as a NFS share which you can access as a regular file system:

- [Mounting EFS file systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html)

Then you just use your **regular python or operating system tools** to operated on the files stored in the EFS filesystem.

For example, in python you can use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) to copy or movie files into and out of your EFS mounted filesystem.

**Boto3**'s interface to EFS is only for its **management**, not for working with files stored on a EFS filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, I would like to access those EFS files, and do something with the files via python script, generate some reports then push those reports to S3, then delete EFS files. Do you think it's possible using shutil itself? thanks.

Comment: @daniel8x Yes. You can just use regular python functions. To open a file in EFS you would use `open` function in python, just like you would when working with your regular local filesystem.

Comment: I do have access point which I have just created. Can I use just python to access files via these access points? Thanks.

Comment: @daniel8x You have to mount it in your operating system, like in the link I provided in the answer.